# Set cursor when mouse over hyperlink in WPF Richt-TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a Rich-Text-Box from Xtended WPF Toolkit to display text bound to some .rtf files. I would like to have the box "ReadOnly" but at the same time I want hyperlinks that are in the files to be active and clickable for the user. In order to achieve this I have the box created like this:

```
<xctk:RichTextBox x:Name="richTextBox" Cursor="Arrow" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding text}"  Focusable="False" IsDocumentEnabled="True">
    <xctk:RichTextBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Hyperlink">
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Arrow" />
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="Hyperlink_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
    </Style>
</xctk:RichTextBox.Resources>
</xctk:RichTextBox>
```

Almost everything works fine and I can click on the links in the Rich-Text-Box, however when the mouse is over the link the cursor turns into a "Text Selection" cursor (the one just like when you hover over a text input field here) and that looks stupid. So it seems this line

```
<Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Arrow" />
```

is being ignored. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Put a complete example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to use this property

```
ForceCursor="true"
```

on your RichTextBox

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an `IsMouseOver` trigger to the `Style` that sets the `IsEnabled` property to `false`:

```
<Style TargetType="Hyperlink">
    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="Hyperlink_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: for some reason adding the "IsMouseOver" Trigger doesn't have any effect in my case